# Not able to login Maximo Anywhere Work Approval apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-7, maximo

I installed Maximo Anywhere 7.5.1.2. We have Worklight 6.1.0.2. I got following error on Worklight console. I have updated Maximo OSLC web resource in web.xml as per mentioned on IBM knowledge center. I appreciate any help

```
[2/22/15 20:09:40:922 EST] 0000002e TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkApproval/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/css/large-landscape-controls.css
[2/22/15 20:10:39:606 EST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkApproval/common/query
[2/22/15 20:10:39:639 EST] 0000002a TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkApproval/common/query
[2/22/15 20:10:39:688 EST] 0000002a TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request URI=/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkApproval/common/query
[2/22/15 20:10:39:719 EST] 0000002a ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet GadgetAPIServlet in application IBM_Worklight_Console. Exception created : com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:548)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:414)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:391)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:384)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:112)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:184)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:75)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:141)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:191)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Link to the document you have read. Explain your scenario.

Comment: I installed Maximo Anywhere 7.5.1.2. I can see error when running on Chrome. Login failed because your user information could not be downloaded. Try again or contact your administrtator

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.1/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.1/security/t_configure_app_server_security.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. Following checklist resolved my issue.

- Assuming you have installed Maximo Anywhere component of Maximo EAM, verify the security groups, ANYWHERE_TECHNICIAN and ANYWHERE_APPROVER are created and have the user assigned to these groups
- Verify if you can make OSLC request from the browser
  http://host:port/maximo/oslc/os/oslcwodetail?_lid=replaceduserid&_lpwd=replacepassword
- clean build the project by touching app.xml file
- deploy the OSLCGenericAdapter
- deploy the app on WorklightDevelopment server from eclipse

  AnywhereWorkManager->apps->WorkApproval->Run As -> Run on Worklight Development Server
- Open the chrome browser and clean the cache
- Preview the app from apps -> WorkApproval -> Common

Comment: I did verify all security and user assigned to these groups. Finally I found issue with worklight.properties. I change si.auth.type=form from maximo and I am able to login in the apps